# Is it possible to write "I'm hungry and tired" (我饿了，我也累了) with a single change-of-state 了?

Tags: particles

> 我饿了，我也累了。

As I understand, both 了s are the [change-of-state 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Change_of_state_with_%22le%22).

I cannot think of a way to write this using only one change-of-state 了, which makes me think it's not possible.  I'm fairly sure "我饿也累了" and "我饿和累了" are both ungrammatical (perhaps a kind of "Englese").

**Question**: Is it possible to write "I'm hungry and tired" with a single change-of-state 了?

Comment: I'd not use 了 to interpret "I'm hungry and tired". I'd say: 我又饿又累 instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing wrong with "我饿了，我也累了。" is the second 我 is redundant.

"我饿了，也累了。" is perfectly grammatical

You can also use  the [又 X 又 Y + 了] structure

Example: 我已經又累又饿了 (I am hungry and tired already)